# Double instance of TighVNC server for 2 different processes on 2 different ports

Tags: port, process

In windows, I would like to launch 2 different processes, and once I have the two process IDs (i.e. PID1 and PID2), I would like to share them via VNC (I know for example that TighVNC allows to share a particular process) over 2 different ports (PORT1, PORT2).

To recap my need would be to access PID1 remotely connecting to the VNCserved using PORT1 and to PID2 remotely connecting to the VNCserved using PORT2.

Is this possible? I know that it is possible to share different monitors on different ports, but I need different Processes on different ports.

Thanks in advance